# Using I2c port as standart GPIO

Tags: rpi.gpio, i2c, pi-2, c++, windows-iot

When I try to use I2c1 SDA pin (GPIO 2 BCM number) via `GpioController::OpenPin()` func, it compiles OK but it throws an exception `HRESULT:0x80070490 Element not found.`

How should I use I2c pins as any other gpio pin like GPIO 5 or 6 for example.

**Note:** *Numbers above are **BCM***

Comment: I have no idea what GpioController does.  It's not a standard C++ library.  Where did you get it?  Is it a library?

Comment: @joan Forgot to mention, I'm using Microsoft Visual Universal App

Comment: So is this a Windows IoT application?

Comment: @joan Yep it is - sorry for long reaction time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a Windows 10 IoT application.

At the moment it does not seem possible to use some gpios as gpios with Windows 10 IoT.

For instance I2C gpios (gpios 2 and 3) and the main SPI gpios (gpios 7, 8, 9, 10, and 11) may only be used for I2C and SPI respectively.

I have not seen any official announcement, perhaps raise a question on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/home?forum=WindowsIoT

Comment: Do you have any information if this "feature" will be avalible in later builds?

Comment: I simply don't know.  If I was you I'd raise the question on the forum I linked, firstly to check what I've said is correct, and, secondly, to show the feature would be of use.

Comment: I've already did. I just wanted to make sure you aren't aware of any possibilities.